# Java DB function, possible return types?

Tags: java

I got into a semi-argument with a co-worker about the following code. I maintain that the code below will either return true (if successful) or an error. He maintains that it's still possible for the function to return false. I don't see how.

However, I have been wrong before in my life.

So, is it possible for the code to return false? If so, how?

```
public static boolean saveBRL(BookingReleaseItem bri) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
    //get connection to mysql database
    Connection conn = getConnection(); 
    //get count of existing items for julian date
    int count = getBRICount(conn, bri.getJulian());

    String query = "INSERT INTO BookingRL "
            + "(julian\n"
            + "serial\n"
            + "name\n"
            + "sid\n"
            + "type\n"
            + "frontDesk\n"
            + "atrReceivedTime\n"
            + "releasing\n"
            + "releaseTime) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";

    PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(query);
    ps.setString(1, bri.getJulian());
    ps.setInt(2, ++count);
    ps.setString(3, bri.getName());
    ps.setString(4, bri.getSid());
    ps.setString(5, bri.getType());
    ps.setString(6, bri.getFrontDesk());
    ps.setString(7, bri.getAtrReceivedTime());
    ps.setString(8, bri.getReleasing());
    ps.setString(9, bri.getReleaseTime());

    ps.executeUpdate();

    ps.close();
    conn.close();

    return true;
}
```

Comment: The only exception to the rule I would be able to think of is if you returned `Boolean.TRUE` and someone reflected the value to be `false`. In short no, it will never return `false`. You should have your coworker try and attempt to explain how, it'll probably poke some nice, big holes in his theory for you.

Comment: It will not return `false`, unless of course if you change the code. Given that, do you really need to return anything?

Comment: There is only one return statement. It returns a literal value. QED.

Comment: *He maintains that it's still possible for the function to return false* - He is wrong, since the method contains just one `return` statement which returns `true`. You are right, this either returns true or throws an exception. What are his arguments?

Comment: "Do not argue with a fool, he will drag you down to his level and beat you with experience"

Comment: Out of subject, use `try`, `catch` and `finally` and close your connection and statement inside finally. otherwise one fine day, this will lead to connection issues

Comment: @secretsuperstar why? what if he uses the same connection somewhere else in the code? it's only useful to close resources once you don't need them anymore, not after each single call. Indeed, if he never wants to communicate to the DB again, close everything

Comment: @secretsuperstar - Since java 7 you should use `try-with-resources` instead.

Comment: @AKSW I agree with you in that case, if it is used later. But if you take a close look at code, the `connection` is opened and closed in the same method. What if there is `exception` and doesn't it cause issues?

Comment: @BackSlash agreed!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To begin with, it is a very bad practice to use a boolean function in case you do not intend to return both values (true/false) under the corresponding circumstances (but I guess that is not the case of your question :) ).

Secondly, since your function **does not use a second return statement that would possibly return a false value**, your co-worker is wrong.

Comment: Indeed - as the method is static, even overriding is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

I am just *guessing* that you're talking about a different code style here. Your code cannot return `false` in any way. The only possibility (and that's what I'm *guessing*) would be if the Exceptions wouldn't be thrown but caught in the method you provided.

Then you *may* return `false` if an Exception occurred. That would be a different way to code this and I would stick to the one that's more common in your code base. If the rest of the company you work for catches the Exceptions, you should do so too.